# Find specific row attribute jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery

On my asp.net form, within a table row I add cells and within those cells I add textboxes with an attribute like -

```
string residentId = (new GUID()).ToString();
string houseId  = (new GUID()).ToString();

HtmlTableRow detailRow = new HtmlTableRow();
detailRow.Attributes.Add("residentId", residentId);
detailRow.Attributes.Add("houseId", houseId);

HtmlTableCell dataCell = new HtmlTableCell();

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Attributes.Add("componentname", "tbMoveInDate");

tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "updateMoveInDate()";

cell.Controls.Add(tb);
detailRow.Cells.Add(dataCell);
```

with a possiblility of 100+ rows, all with distinct IDs of course.

within my javascript I have this function -

```
function updateMoveInDate() {
    var MoveInDateEle = $("[componentname*='tbMoveInDate']");
}
```

at this point MoveInDateEle is a collection of all of those text boxes within the table and

```
var currentRow = $("[componentname*='tbMoveInDate']").parent().parent();
```

gives me all of the rows. but not my specific row.

How is it possible to get the specific text box I am working with and the specific resident Id and house Id associated with that control?

Comment: Are you clicking on the row you are working with or what does `working with` mean? Will the textbox be focused? Would you mind explaining a bit more. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "updateMoveInDate(this)";
```

And

```
function updateMoveInDate(txt) {
    var $txt = $(txt);
    var $row = $txt.closest('tr');
    var residentId = $row.attr('residentId');
    var houseId = $row.attr('houseId');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify the `C#` code like this:

```
tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "updateMoveInDate(this)";
```

and the js function like:

```
// obj here refers to the current textbox in the scope
// on which the on-change event had occurred...
function updateMoveInDate(obj) {
    var currentRow = $(obj).closest('tr');
}
```

Comment: @edhedges That's because OP is using `$("[componentname*='tbMoveInDate']")` which refers to all the textboxes but we are using here `this` keyword, which refers to the element in the current scope, not to the full collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "updateMoveInDate(this)";
```

in code behind

```
    string residentId = (new GUID()).ToString();
    string houseId  = (new GUID()).ToString();

    HtmlTableRow detailRow = new HtmlTableRow();
    detailRow.Attributes.Add("residentId", residentId);
    detailRow.Attributes.Add("houseId", houseId);

    HtmlTableCell dataCell = new HtmlTableCell();

    TextBox tb = new TextBox();
    tb.Attributes.Add("componentname", "tbMoveInDate");

    tb.Attributes.Add("onchange", "updateMoveInDate(this)";

    cell.Controls.Add(tb);
    detailRow.Cells.Add(dataCell);
```

jQuery:

```
function updateMoveInDate(args) {
    var MoveInDateEle = $(args).closest('tr');

}
```